# Error sentencia PL SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

Tengo que hacer un insert en SQL Server.

He probado lo siguiente, pero no sé si estará bien, a primera vista me da un fallo cerca del `IF` y del `THEN`, pero no sé por qué. Imagino que será por el `AND` de la condición.

```
USE [BD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertRatio] 
@descripcion varchar(255), 
@pHora int, 
@pPrecio int, 
@pIdZona int,
@codigo_msg INT OUT,
@existeh int,
@existep int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
Begin Tran TransInsertRatio
    Begin Try   
        set @existeh = (select horasRD FROM dbo.TBLRatioDescuento where horasRD = 20)
        set @existep = (select DescuentoRD FROM dbo.TBLRatioDescuento where DescuentoRD = 20)

        IF @existeh IS NULL AND @existep IS NULL THEN

            INSERT INTO [TBLRatioDescuento] ([idZona],[descripcionRD],[horasRD],[descuentoRd])
            VALUES (2, "Máximo 20 h",20,20)
        END IF;

    End try
    Begin Catch

        set @codigo_msg = 1

        Rollback TRAN TransInsertVehiculo

    End Catch

END
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

> ```
> Mens 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Procedimiento spInsertRatio, Línea 17
> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'THEN'.
> Mens 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Procedimiento spInsertRatio, Línea 21
> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'IF'.
> ```

Comment: Hola Urrutias puedes añadir el error que te da el `IF`?

Comment: Hola urrutias. Toma en cuenta que PL/SQL es un lenguaje utilizado por Oracle, no SQL Server. Entonces, sería bueno aclarar por qué mencionas PL SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En SQL Server no puedes usar IF - THEN - END IF

Tienes que usar:

**Sintaxis**

> IF Boolean_expression
>       { sql_statement | statement_block }
>   [ ELSE
>       { sql_statement | statement_block } ]

```
IF @existeh IS NULL AND @existep IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [TBLRatioDescuento] ([idZona],[descripcionRD],[horasRD],[descuentoRd])
    VALUES (2, "Máximo 20 h",20,20)
END
```

Mira la documentacion de Microsoft sobre [IF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms182717(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: Si, ya lo arregl, muchas gracias, hacia mucho que no tocaba sql server